# Оптимизация преобразования int в hex

Tags: java, android, массивы, hex, конвертация

Занимаюсь оптимизацией кода. Прошу помощи
Я получаю массив (внутри int) на обработку

```
    private void byte_to_hex(byte[] arg1) {
    try {
        i2 = 0;
        while (i2 < arg1.length / 16) {
            arg_3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arg1, i2 * 16, 16 + i2 * 16);
            String[] _SS_usb_temp_0 = new String[arg_3.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < arg_3.length; j++) {
                _SS_usb_temp_0[j] = Int_2_Hex(arg1[j]);
            }
            _send_ID(_SS_usb_temp_0);
            i2 = i2 + 1;
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    }
}
```

да, криво немного, согласен. Но давайте дальше.

```
public static String Int_2_Hex(int int_value) {
    String tt = int_value < 0
            ? Integer.toHexString(256 + int_value)
            : Integer.toHexString(int_value);
    if (tt.length() == 1) {
        return "0" + tt.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        return tt.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

С этим преобразованием загрузка процессора 35% примерно. Но при этом в логах я вижу потерю пакетов

```
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 137445(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 343us total 143.127ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 139013(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 5.135ms total 148.789ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 136877(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 325us total 117.309ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 138396(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 361us total 132.995ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 128695(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 93us total 103.841ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 132061(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 205us total 132.478ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 136010(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 314us total 149.794ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 136929(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 325us total 112.468ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 127767(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/7MB, paused 317us total 117.676ms
```

Ок. Я переписываю эту функцию по-другому

```
public static String Int_2_Hex_2(int int_value) {
    if (int_value < 0) {
        int_value = 256 + int_value;
    }
    return String.format("%02X", int_value);
}
```

Вроде короче. Но при этом загрузка процессора 120%, а потери пакетов почти нет

```
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 184290(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/11MB, paused 293us total 126.500ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 176036(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 863us total 126.154ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 163066(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 104us total 143.060ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 149205(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 212us total 120.340ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 168632(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 204us total 129.314ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 186139(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4MB/9MB, paused 332us total 122.604ms
I/sicilla.VestaG: Background concurrent copying GC freed 188790(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4MB/9MB, paused 154us total 122.539ms
```

Помогите найти золотую середину между загрузкой и потерей пакетов.
Оставить преобразование в hex пока нужно, у меня очень большой код обработки сигнала, он на hex ориентирован.

Comment: Что по загрузке ядер? 120% явно несколько работают, но я так понимаю чтение происходит в 1 потоке?

Comment: Загрузку ядер система же распределяет. Да, всё в 1 потоке. Если делать потоков, путаница с сигналами начинается

Comment: загоняйте целые ряды символов в потоки и потом объединяйте результат

Comment: Зачем объединять? Мне наоборот надо разбивать

Comment: Ну чтобы все ядра были заняты трансляцией hex -> string.

Comment: А что, в программе можно указать, сколько ядер использовать? Это не так просто